# How to make a message into a polynomial?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ntruencrypt

I'm doing a project where I have to implement the NTRUEncrypt public key cryptosystem. This is the first step according to their guide in encrypting - "Alice, who wants to send a secret message to Bob, puts her message in the form of a polynomial m with coefficients {-1,0,1}" . I want to know how I can make my message into a polynomial. Thank you.

Comment: If you intend to rely on this implementation for security, rather than this being pedagogical in nature, you're in for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it however you like. Perhaps the most straightforward way is to convert your message to a ternary representation

```
"Hello" -> 72, 101, 108, 108, 111 -> 02200, 10202, 11000, 11000, 11010
```

So I'm converting the characters to their ASCII representation and then converting those representations to their ternary representation (assuming that I'm limited to the 7-bit ASCII space I only need five ternary digits).

Then convert the ternary representation to a polynomial on `{-1, 0, 1}` by mapping the ternary digit `0` to `0`, the ternary digit `1` to `1` and the ternary digit `2` to `-1` and assuming that the digit corresponding to 3^k is the coefficient of x^k<sup>1</sup>:

```
02200 -> p1(x) = 0 +    0 * x + (-1) * x^2 + (-1) * x^3 + 0 * x^4
10202 -> p2(x) = (-1) + 0 * x + (-1) * x^2 +    0 * x^3 + 1 * x^4
11000 -> p3(x) = 0    + 0 * x +    0 * x^2 +    1 * x^3 + 1 * x^4
11000 -> p4(x) = 0    + 0 * x +    0 * x^2 +    1 * x^3 + 1 * x^4
11010 -> p5(x) = 0    + 1 * x +    0 * x^2 +    1 * x^3 + 1 * x^4
```

and then my message is

```
p1(x) + x^5 * p2(x) + (x^5)^2 * p3(x) + (x^5)^3 * p4(x) + (x^5)^4 * p5(x)
```

so that my polynomial's coefficients are

```
(0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1).
```

Regardless how you do it, the point is that you can represent your message as a polynomial however you like. It's just preferred that you find a bijection from your message space to the space of polynomials on `{-1, 0, 1}` that is easily computed and has an easily computed inverse.

<sup>1</sup> This is the crux of the transformation. A five-digit ternary number `a`<sub>`4`</sub>`a`<sub>`3`</sub>`a`<sub>`2`</sub>`a`<sub>`1`</sub>`a`<sub>`0`</sub> corresponds exactly to evaluating the polynomial `a`<sub>`4`</sub> `* x^4 + a`<sub>`3`</sub> `* x^3 + a`<sub>`2`</sub> `* x^2 +a`<sub>`1`</sub> `* x + a`<sub>`0`</sub> `* x^0` at `x = 3`. So there is an obvious one-to-one correspondence between polynomials on `{-1, 0, 1}` and ternary numbers.

Comment: Good answer. Might want to point out the more common approach of generating a random symmetric key, then encrypting _that_ with the public key algorithm, too.

Comment: That's really helpful answer but i would like to specify few details which are not understandable to me. Why do you express a five-digit ternary as a4a3a2a1a0 and not backward, from 0 to 4? Is it important somehow? Also i do not understand why x = 3. What does it mean? And when you make your message as p1(x) + x^5 * p2(x) + (x^5)^2 * p3(x) + (x^5)^3 * p4(x) + (x^5)^4 * p5(x) - the power of x is five cause message consists of 5 characters, right? Sorry for asking all these dumb questions but i really need to understand how the stuff works.

Comment: @Andrey Chernukha: *Why do you express a five-digit ternary as a4a3a2a1a0 and not backward, from 0 to 4?* It's standard practice to give the index of the subscript (i.e., the 0, 1, 2, etc.) the same value as the value of the exponent (i.e., `a_j` corresponds to the coefficient of `x^j`). *Is it important somehow?* Only insofar as it's standard practice and it makes following along easier. You, could, if you wanted, write `a33a52a21a104a69` and declare that `a69` is the coefficient of `x^0`, etc. but you will quickly lose readers as it's much harder to follow along.

Comment: @Andrey Chernukha: *Also i do not understand why `x = 3`. What does it mean?* Because we are talking about a ternary expansion. Just like the base-10 number `143` means `1 * 10^2 + 4 * 10^1 + 3 * 10^0`, the base-3 number `12022` means  1 * 3^4 + 2 * 3^3 + 0 * 3^2 + 2 * 3^1 + 2 * 3^0`. Note that this means that `143` is the same as evaluating the polynomial `p(x) = 1 * x^2 + 4 * x^1 + 3 * x^0` at `x = 10` and `12022` is the same as evaluating the polynomial `q(x) = 1 * x^4 + 2 * x^3 + 0 * x^2 + 2 * x^1 + 2 * x^0` at `x = 3`.

Comment: @Andrey Chernukha: *And when you make your message as `p1(x) + x^5 * p2(x) + (x^5)^2 * p3(x) + (x^5)^3 * p4(x) + (x^5)^4 * p5(x)` - the power of `x` is five cause message consists of 5 characters, right?*. No, it's because I'm assuming 7-bit ASCII, and thus I need five ternary bits to represent all of the possible 7-bit ASCII characters. Then, to separate the characters, we have multiply the polynomial corresponding to each one by successive powers of `x^5` (that's why you see `x^5`, `(x^5)^2`, etc.) so that none of the polynomials have any common terms. Do you see why we want that?

Comment: First -Thank you VERY MUCH for your explanation.Second - your explanation helped me to understand a lot, but not everything (English is not my native language and polynomials is not the easiest thing to be learned). So i have few more dumb questions. 1)No, i cannot grasp why we want polynomials to not have any common terms. Maybe because some of cofficients are nulls, no? 2) This question is really stupid, but..... how exactly looks FINAL version of the polynomial? p1(x) + x^5*p2(x) + (x^5)^2*p3(x) + (x^5)^3 *p4(x) + (x^5)^4*p5(x) = p1(x) +x^5 *p2(x) + x^10 *p3(x) + x^15*p4(x) + x^20*p5(x)

Comment: = -x^2 -x^3 - x^5 - x^7 + x^9 + x^13 + x^14 + x^18 + x^19 + x^20 + x^23 + x^24. Am i right?

Comment: Andrey Chernukha: The reason that you don't want the polynomials to have any common terms is the same reason that when you write a letter by hand to someone, you don't write letters on top of each other. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 3):

I work for NTRU, so I'm glad to see this interest.

The IEEE standard 1363.1-2008 specifies how to implement NTRUEncrypt with the most current parameter sets. The method it specifies for binary->trinary conversion is:

> Convert each three-bit quantity to two
>   ternary coefficients as follows, and
>   concatenate the resulting ternary
>   quantities to obtain [the output].

```
{0, 0, 0} -> {0, 0}
{0, 0, 1} -> {0, 1}
{0, 1, 0} -> {0, -1}
{0, 1, 1} -> {1, 0}
{1, 0, 0} -> {1, 1}
{1, 0, 1} -> {1, -1}
{1, 1, 0} -> {-1, 0}
{1, 1, 1} -> {-1, 1}
```

To convert back:

> Convert each set of two ternary
>   coefficients to three bits as follows,
>   and concatenate the resulting bit
>   quantities to obtain [the output]:

```
{0, 0} -> {0, 0, 0}
{0, 1} -> {0, 0, 1}
{0, -1} -> {0, 1, 0}
{1, 0} -> {0, 1, 1}
{1, 1} -> {1, 0, 0}
{1, -1} -> {1, 0, 1}
{-1, 0} -> {1, 1, 0}
{-1, 1} -> {1, 1, 1}
{-1, -1} -> set "fail" to 1 and set bit string to {1, 1, 1}
```

Note that to encrypt a message securely you can't simply convert the message to trinary and apply raw NTRU encryption. The message needs to be pre-processed before encryption and post-processed after encryption to protect against active attackers who might modify the message in transit. The necessary processing is specified in IEEE Std 1363.1-2008, and discussed in our 2003 paper "NAEP: Provable Security in the Presence of Decryption Failures" (Available from http://www.ntru.com/cryptolab/articles.htm#2003_3, though be aware that this description is targeted at binary polynomials rather than trinary).

Hope this helps.

@Bert: at various times we've recommended binary or trinary polynomials. Trinary polynomials allow the same security with shorter keys. However, in the past we thought that binary polynomials allowed q (the big modulus) to be 256. This was attractive for 8-bit processors. We've since established that taking q = 256 reduces security unacceptably (specifically, it makes decryption failures too likely). Since we no longer have small q as a goal, we can take advantage of trinary polynomials to give smaller keys overall.